# Better way to do multiple timed events, each having its own interval?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to do a traffic light countdown for pedestrians.

When reaching this section, it will repeat each step until it's over 10 sec (it will ran for 10sec, then it will move on to other tasks):

- The red light will flash on and off, with on for 0.8 sec, and off for
  0.8 sec.
- The buzzer will sound every 1.6 sec.
- The digit LED display will countdown from 9, every 1 sec, until zero.

I currently ran 2 timers, one for buzzer, leds, and another for the digit LED. The bool at__Ran is to ensure that it is only activates once, until it reaches 1.6 sec, where it loops back. This is because the if (countdown - countdown_last == XXX) will activates multiple times, before millis updates.

There is what I got:

```c
  unsigned long time_start = millis();
  unsigned long time_over = millis() + 10001;
  unsigned long countdown_1sec = millis();
  unsigned long countdown = millis();
  unsigned long countdown_last = millis();
  unsigned long countdown_last_1sec = millis();
  int countdownNum = 9;
  bool atZeroRan = false;
  bool at800Ran = false;
  bool at1600Ran = false;

  while(countdown < time_over) {
    if (countdown - countdown_last == 0 && atZeroRan == false) {
      digitalWrite(pedR, HIGH);
      tone(buzzer, 973, 15);
      at1600Ran = false;
      atZeroRan = true;
    }
    if (countdown - countdown_last == 800 && at800Ran == false) {
      digitalWrite(pedR, LOW);
      atZeroRan = false;
      at800Ran = true;
    }
    if (countdown_1sec - countdown_last_1sec == 1000) {
      countdown_last_1sec = millis();
      displayNumber(countdownNum);
      countdownNum = countdownNum - 1;
    }
    if (countdown - countdown_last == 1600 && at1600Ran == false) {
      countdown_last = millis();
      at800Ran = false;
      at1600Ran = true;
    }
    countdown_1sec = millis();
    countdown = millis();
  }

  digitalWrite(pedR, HIGH);
```

While this *mostly* works, sometimes the program doesn't do the
routine (e.g., the digit will not countdown or update, the red light
won't turn on or off) or that the countdown would randomly stop to
update around 5-8 seconds in. I do not know the "trigger" that causes
those bugs. I do not believe that it is the problem with circuitry.

Is there any way I can optimize this code and hopefully fixes the issues as well?

Comment: Provide more info about `millis()`.  Does that _always_ return the next millisecond, or might it skip a value?  (E.g. code did not call it fast enough)  I suppose it is like [this](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/), yet is your code quick enough?

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't behave as you expect because of exact comparisons for timing. i.e. `countdown - countdown_last == 800` `countdown - countdown_last == 1600`.

This fails because you expect the program to execute that line at exactly 800 or 1600 ms, which is never guaranteed in systems like Arduino.

I would suggest using timer interrupts instead of hard comparisons for timing. They also have a timer library `TimerEvent.h`, which abstracts out the software implementation of interrupt.
And if you would want comparisons, use a range instead of exact values.

Answer (score 0):

As `Serial.println` or other functions and operations take some time, strong conditions, like `countdown - countdown_last == 1600`, are very likely to not work.

You need to change your program logic.

Comment: the Serial.println is for debugging and is not related to the program, please see updated code.

Comment: @P.Z. it does not matter - your logic is still wrong

Comment: In that case, how can I improve it?

Comment: do not use stong comparisons

Comment: Re *"are very likely to not work."*: Perhaps explain *why* in the answer?